# FFMPEG - Split 3D video to collection of 2 images

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-editing

I want to split a Side-By-Side 3D video to the 2 images and store them as JPEG (or PNG). This should result in 24 images (left image and right image) per second for the whole movie.

I know there's a command like `ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -filter:v "crop=out_w:out_h:x:y" out.mp4` to crop parts of the video but I want it to automatically find the center of the width and cut the video in half and then store the images.

can I do something like this using solely FFMPEG on Windows 10? and if there is a way to do it, can the frame-rate frequency be customized? for example 5 images (left and right images) per second instead of 24.

by the way I can also use the Linux Bash available in the Windows 10 Anniversary edition.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, thanks to user c97 I ended up with this command which does the job:

`ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -r 1/1 -filter:v "crop=(iw/2):ih:0:0" %03d-left.jpg -r 1/1 -filter:v "crop=(iw/2):ih:(iw/2):0" %03d-right.jpg`

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -filter:v "crop=(iw/2):ih:0:0" out_lefthalf.mp4`

There are lots of examples in ffmpeg documentation, you can read it at https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#crop

Comment: Your command gives me a video output whereas I need image outputs... I ended up modifying it to `ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -r 1/1 -filter:v "crop=(iw/2):ih:0:0" %03d-left.jpg` which gives me the left-side images of the 3D movie... can I modify this command somehow to make it give me both the half left and half right images with corresponding names?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use

```
ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -vf "stereo3d=out=ml" -r 1 %03d-left.jpg -vf "stereo3d=out=mr" -r 1 %03d-right.jpg
```